# How can I record audio directly from the browser

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, applet, webrtc

I'd like to allow my visitors to record an audio file with their microphone directly from the website. Something compatible IE, Mozilla, Chrome.

What are the different ways to do it ? What about WebRTC ?

Comment: Whatever is gonna be the solution, webrtc definitely has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Actually, `getUserMedia()`, the API that grants access to the user's microphone, is considered a part of WebRTC (the other party being `RTCPeetConnection`).

Comment: As of this writing, I realize getUserMedia() is not yet mature enough to be supported by all the browsers. I made something with flash/js/php that allows the user to record an audio file to be automatically uploaded on the server. This solution works for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at [this project](https://github.com/Mido22/recordOpus), records in compressed ogg format, no need for flash, and in firefox's case, no need of any library too. sorry, but it doesn't work in IE since `getUserMedia` is not supported there.

Comment: Microsoft Edge supports `getUserMedia()` FWIW.